# AD Group Membership Removal Script Not Working 100% - Need Assistance

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'll start off by saying that I am not a scripting expert at all.  But I was tasked with creating a script to remove all group memberships of all users in a specified OU (called DISABLE) a few months ago.

Long story short, the script works great most of the time, but on random occasions it won't remove 1 (random) group for a user , or 2, or sometimes more, and I can't figure out what the reasoning is.  The script used is:

```
#Remove User Group Memberships
$ou = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=DISABLE,OU=CE,DC=ourdomain,DC=org" -Filter *
foreach ($user in $ou) {
$UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
$user.PrimaryGroupID = 513
set-aduser -instance $user
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$UserDN)" | foreach-object {
if ($_.name -ne "Domain Users") {remove-adgroupmember -identity $_.name -
member $UserDN -Confirm:$False} }
}
```

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you maybe have multiple domains? Try to figure out logic  about skipped groups, and it will give you a hint. Specially, check group scope and if group is in ourdomain.org or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for users, and then searching for all groups that user is a member of, just include that in your first search. This has the benefit of fewer AD searches, and less chance that an AD search misses the user.

```
#Remove User Group Memberships
$ou = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=DISABLE,OU=CE,DC=ourdomain,DC=org" -Filter * -Property MemberOf
foreach ($user in $ou) {
    $UserDN = $user.DistinguishedName
    $user.PrimaryGroupID = 513
    set-aduser -instance $user
    $user.MemberOf | 
        Where{$_ -notmatch "Domain.?Users"} | 
        ForEach {remove-adgroupmember -identity $_ -member $UserDN -Confirm:$False}
}
```

Try that and see if you get better mileage out of it. Also, consider that perhaps some of these are protected groups, and the account that you run the script under doesn't have rights to affect those groups. Check these users that aren't being removed from groups and see if they have their `AdminCount` property set to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I'll test out that adjusted script and see if I have better luck with it.  I have confirmed it's not a permissions issue though, as my standard account was able to remove the groups the script did not remove, and the script is ran with Domain Administrator privileges.  Thanks again, I'll post back once I confirm how the new script works!

Comment: The script has been working successfully for 2 weeks now, so I believe you have solved my issue.  Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help with this!